# Is it possible to broadcast Tensorflow libraries using spark-submit -package

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow

I am using a cluster, which is not managed by myself. Tensorflow libraries are not installed on any cluster nodes. But I would like to run some Spark programs using tensorflow package. I am not sure if it is possible to simply use spark-submit --packages to broadcast tensorflow packages across the cluster nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Tensorflow itself, but you can pass a [local jars](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management) using `--jars` and files using `--files` to the job. Below is an example:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 5 --driver-memory 640m --executor-memory 640m --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1000 \
    --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client-1.6.1/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client-1.6.1/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client-1.6.1/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar  \
    --files /usr/hdp/current/spark-client-1.6.1/conf/hive-site.xml \
    --class com.foobar.main
```

This is an example of how I start spark streaming job and the Application Master and Driver run on the cluster where spark is not installed. So I need to pass a long some jars and configs for it to run.